# unable to find htdoc folder in windows vista for apache7.0.25

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat

I tried looking for  htdoc folder in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\ directory.
Checked each and every subfolder but unable to find it plz help.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A htdocs folder is a special folder where the Apache HTTP server stores its documents.

Apache Tomcat (a servlet engine) has no such thing.

Looks like your question has some mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your apache configuration and search for DirectoryRoot. It should be configured there.

You can also download XAMPP from http://www.apachefriends.org/. It works great for web development on windows and has everything you need.

Comment: can you please specify the path and filename for configuration?because i looked for every file in directory of apache for .conf file but there's none.

Comment: The configuration usualy resides in /directory/to/your/apache/conf/httpd.conf there also might be other conf files containig virtual hosts but this should serve as a good starting point.

Comment: sorry,it's not working for me can you specify tomcat version you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you are talking about the apache http server. 

If you are using Tomcat, you have to deploy webapps (e.g. war files) into your webapps directory. Those webapps can contain html/css/images as well as scripts and servlets...